# Modifying an activeadmin module to hide breadcrumbs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

There are some issues with Active Admin on chained belongs_to.  Among other things it causes the breadcrumbs to sometimes show the wrong links.

I was hoping to find a way of simply hiding the breadcrumbs on some (but not all) pages by modifying the active admin breadcrumb helper in an initializer.  F ex:

```
module ActiveAdmin
 module ViewHelpers
  module BreadcrumbHelper


    def breadcrumb_links(path = request.path)
      if @hidebread 
        false
      else
        parts = path[1..-1].split('/') # remove leading "/" and split up the URL
        parts.pop                      # remove last since it's used as the page title

        parts.each_with_index.map do |part, index|
          # 1. try using `display_name` if we can locate a DB object
          # 2. try using the model name translation
          # 3. default to calling `titlecase` on the URL fragment
          if part =~ /\A(\d+|[a-f0-9]{24})\z/ && parts[index-1]
            parent = active_admin_config.belongs_to_config.try :target
            config = parent && parent.resource_name.route_key == parts[index-1] ? parent : active_admin_config
            name   = display_name config.find_resource part
          end
          name ||= I18n.t "activerecord.models.#{part.singularize}", :count => ActiveAdmin::Helpers::I18n::PLURAL_MANY_COUNT, :default => part.titlecase

          link_to name, '/' + parts[0..index].join('/')
        end
      end

    end

  end
 end
end
```

This gives the error “uninitialized constant ActiveAdmin::Helpers::I18n” though.  Understanding how to fix this sadly goes a bit beyond my Rails skills.  Is there a way to work around this, or is there a way to call something like a “super” on a module so that I could do something similar to

```
    def breadcrumb_links(path = request.path)
      if @hidebread 
        false
      else
        super
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was just added to the latest version of ActiveAdmin about 2.5 weeks ago.

```
# Gemfile
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'

# app/admin/my_model.rb
ActiveAdmin.register MyModel do
  config.breadcrumb = false
end
```

Comment: Oh, fantastic!  I had missed that.  Very grateful!